how to change MUI BOX component?
I am trying to make it BOX width to 100% but it is not working...
I knew how to use sx prop to change but i dont know why it is not working this time ...
here is my code
   <Box width={100} sx={{ border: "2px solid grey" }}>   

width 100px is applied well,so I guess width={"100%"} should work but it is not...
so I tried using sx prop like above code..
 <Box sx={{ border: "2px solid grey",width:"100%" }}> 

it is not working ... except width, other prop is working good such as border
this screenshot is make sure that parent's container width is full with border line
enter image description here
Could you please help me ??
I want box container width change to full
I am using Material-Table library link : https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/detail-panel#render-detail-panel
And here is Full Code
  // ------------workstate cell options-----------------
  const workCell = ({ row, accessorKey }) => {
    const status = row.original[accessorKey];
    let textColorClass = "";
    switch (status) {
      case 1:
        textColorClass = "text-green-500";
        break;
      case 0:
        textColorClass = "text-slate-500";
        break;
      case -1:
        textColorClass = "text-base-200";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return (
      <div className={`${textColorClass} text-3xl`}>
        <button onClick={handleOnClick}>
          <IoIosRadioButtonOn />
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const workStateOption = {
    size: 80,
    enableEditing: false,
    enableClickToCopy: false,
  };
  // ------------workstate cell options-----------------

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        accessorKey: "RequiredDate",
        header: "Date",
        sx: { width: 10000 },
        Cell: ({ row }) => {
          const today = new Date();
          const date = row.original.RequiredDate;
          const trimmedDate = date.split("T")[0];
          const dateObj = new Date(trimmedDate);
          const oneWeekAgo = new Date(today);
          const dueCheck = oneWeekAgo.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);
          let status;
          if (dateObj < today) {
            status = "overdue";
          } else if (dateObj > today) {
            status = "a month ago";
          } else if (dateObj < dueCheck) {
            status = "a week ago";
          } else {
            status = "today";
          }
          const day = dateObj.getDate();
          const month = dateObj.toLocaleDateString("default", {
            month: "short",
          });
          const year = dateObj.getFullYear().toString();
          const formattedDate = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;

          return (
            <span
              className={`${
                (status === "overdue" && "bg-rose-300 text-rose-950") ||
                (status === "today" && "bg-slate-600 text-slate-900") ||
                (status === "a month ago" && "bg-green-300 text-green-800") ||
                (status === "a week ago" && "bg-orange-300 text-orange-800")
              } p-1 rounded-lg`}
            >
              {formattedDate}
            </span>
          );
        },
        size: 150,
        enableEditing: false,
        enableClickToCopy: false,
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "JobNo",
        header: "Job Number",
        size: 150,
        enableEditing: false,
        enableClickToCopy: true,
        Cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className="bg-white rounded-lg">
            <div
              className={`text-purple-500 font-bold bg-purple-100 p-1 rounded-lg font-mono`}
            >
              {row.original.JobNo}
            </div>
          </div>
        ),
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "customer",
        header: "Customer",
        size: 200,
        enableEditing: false,
        enableClickToCopy: true,
        Cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div
            className={`${
              row.original.Customer === undefined
                ? null
                : "text-blue-500 font-bold bg-blue-100 text-center py-1 px-2 rounded-lg font-mono"
            } `}
          >
            {row.original.Customer}
          </div>
        ),
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "SH",
        header: "SH",
        ...workStateOption,
        Cell: ({ row }) => workCell({ row, accessorKey: "SH" }),
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "PR",
        header: "PR",
        ...workStateOption,
        Cell: ({ row }) => workCell({ row, accessorKey: "PR" }),
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "PA",
        header: "PA",
        ...workStateOption,
        Cell: ({ row }) => workCell({ row, accessorKey: "PA" }),
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "DS",
        header: "DS",
        ...workStateOption,
        Cell: ({ row }) => workCell({ row, accessorKey: "DS" }),
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "~",
        header: "Total",
        ...workStateOption,
        Cell: ({ row }) => workCell({ row, accessorKey: "~" }),
      },
    ],
    [fetcheddata]
  );

  return {
    columns,
    enableClickToCopy: true,
    enableStickyHeader: true,
    enableStickyFooter: true,
    enableExpandAll: true,
    enableExpanding: true,
    filterFromLeafRows: true,
    data: fetcheddata,
    paginateExpandedRows: false,
    layoutMode: "grid",
    enableEditing: true,
    editDisplayMode: "cell",
    enableColumnPing: true,
    positionExpandColumn: "last",

    //-------------- body cell props---------------------------//
    muiTableBodyCellProps: ({ cell, column, table, row }) => ({
      // onClick: () => {
      //   table.setEditingCell(cell);
      //   queueMicrotask(() => {
      //     const textField = table.refs.editInputRefs.current[column.id];
      //     if (textField) {
      //       textField.focus();
      //       textField.select?.();
      //     }
      //   });
      // },
      sx: {
        backgroundColor: row.getIsExpanded() ? "#fffbe3" : "",
      },
    }),
    //-------------- body cell props-------------------------------//

    enableColumnActions: false,
    style: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      overflow: "auto",
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
    },

    displayColumnDefOptions: {
      "mrt-row-actions": {
        header: "Details",
        size: 50,
      },
    },

    initialState: {
      columnPinning: {
        left: isMobile ? ["jobNumber"] : [],
      },
    },
    renderDetailPanel: ({ row }) => {
      const [note, setNote] = useState(row.original.Note);
      if (row.original.Note) {
        return (
          <Box sx={{ border: "2px solid grey", width: "100%" }}>{note}</Box>

        );
      }
      return "No Notesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss";
    },
    muiDetailPanelProps: () => ({
      sx: (theme) => ({
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
        width: "100%",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        border: "1px solid black",
      }),
    }),
  };
};



Can you please post your parent component and its styles?

Hi Ahmet, I added parent component with styles
Thanks :)

If you simply remove display: "flex" in muiDetailPanelProps sx, it works. See this stackblitz. Does that work in your case too?

I removed display: "flex", but it still doesn't work. But when I changed DetailPanelwith width: "100%", It worked.   I don't know why Box width doesn't changed. I uploaded the full code. Could you please have a look?
